# .NET Core 3.0 Identity issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to update my projects to .NET Core 3.0 and .NET Standard 2.1 (including .NET Core Identity)

I have 2 projects. First my Web API:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

And in this project code related with Identity works fine.

As I see here I need to remove package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

2-nd project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />-->
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />-->
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

So, if I remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` from my second project I see error:

> The type or namespace name '`SignInManager<>`' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I add this line:

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

I see this error:

> Error NETSDK1073 The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized

How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: Perhaps instead of a `TargetFramework` of `netstandard2.1` you should be using `netcoreapp3.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756#issuecomment-434114175) Github Issue which explains a lot of the changes. As said in one of the comments.

> Correct. We are removing the netstandard2.0 from most Microsoft.AspNetCore.* assemblies. See [#3754](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3754)

So in order to use the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` in your `.csproj` you will need to target `netcoreapp3.0` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this issue after downgrading visual studio enterprise 2019 to professional 2019.

.Net core framework netcoreapp3.1

I fixed it by updating the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4.